# PDO prepare error, Parse error

Tags: php, pdo

I can perform the following PDO query successfully:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .DB_HOST.';dbname=' .DB_NAME. '', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$query = "SELECT ITEM_ID, LISTING_TITLE, PURCHASE_AMT FROM INVNTRY.ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID IN (1,2);";

$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['LISTING_TITLE'];
}
```

Then close the cursor and db connection.

I mainly showed the above code to illustrate that my database connection is successful:

When I execute this code I get an error on the "prepare" line:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .DB_HOST.';dbname=' .DB_NAME. '', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT ITEM_ID, LISTING_TITLE, PURCHASE_AMT FROM INVNTRY.ITEM WHERE LISTING_TITLE = ?');

$array - array('Black Duffle Bag');
$query->execute($array);
$fetch = $query->fetch();
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db' (T_VARIABLE)
```

I know this is normally due to a missing ; or something similar, but I think I have this coded correctly. Is there any configuration file setting required prior to performing a prepare? I am running this second code base on the same instance as the first.

Comment: The error occurs before the code you posted. As you said, probably a missing semicolon. Start from the line mentioned in the code and work backwards a line or so from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem in this code is line:

```
$array - array('Black Duffle Bag');
```

It must be:

```
$array = array('Black Duffle Bag');
```

I tried your code with modify above and it works with no error!

Comment: Interesting that when you changed the hyphen to = (which was clearly an error in my code) that it works on your system. After you pointed this out I tried it on mine and it still fails with the same error. Makes me wonder if there is some ini file or other set up that needs to be tweaked.